# Symfony: Could not load type "EWZ\Bundle\RecaptchaBundle\Form\Type\RecaptchaType"

Tags: php, symfony, formbuilder, ezplatform

I installed bundle `excelwebzone/recaptcha-bundle` by composer
on Symfony 2.7.8, added to bundles:

```
new EWZ\Bundle\RecaptchaBundle\EWZRecaptchaBundle()
```

added reCAPTCHA to form builder in my custom controller and got error:

> Could not load type `"EWZ\Bundle\RecaptchaBundle\Form\Type\RecaptchaType"`
>   in `vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormRegistry.php` at line 83

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution in [this tutorial](http://pythonhackers.com/p/markopavlovic/EWZRecaptchaBundle):

In Symfony 2.7 I have to write:

```
$builder->add('recaptcha', 'ewz_recaptcha');
```

Instead of:

```
$builder->add('recaptcha', 'EWZ\Bundle\RecaptchaBundle\Form\Type\RecaptchaType');
```

The initial solution probably works in Symfony >=2.8.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at https://github.com/excelwebzone/EWZRecaptchaBundle/blob/master/Form/Type/EWZRecaptchaType.php, the class name is `EWZRecaptchaType` (not only `RecaptchaType` without the leading `EWZ`).

Comment: Class name is correct, my EWZRecaptchaBundle is version 1.4 (last stable in composer repository). namespace EWZ\Bundle\RecaptchaBundle\Form\Type; class RecaptchaType extends AbstractType
{

Comment: Can you please show which version of the bundle you have installed (run `composer show -i excelwebzone/recaptcha-bundle` to get the version)?

Comment: name     : excelwebzone/recaptcha-bundle
descrip. : This bundle provides easy reCAPTCHA form field integration
keywords : recaptcha
versions : * v1.4.1
type     : symfony-bundle